# JOIN query too slow on real database, on small one it runs fine

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, join

I need help with this mysql query that executes too long or does not execute at all.

(What I am trying to do is a part of more complex problem, where I want to create PHP cron script that will execute few heavy queries and calculate data from the results returned and then use those data to store it in database for further more convenient use. Most likely I will make question here about that process.)

First lets try to solve one of the problems with these heavy queries.

Here is the thing:

I have table: **users_bonitet**. This table has fields: **id**, **user_id**, **bonitet**, **tstamp**.

First important note: when I say **user**, please understand that users are actually **companies**, not people. So user.id is id of some company, but for some other reasons table that I am using here is called "**users**".

Three key fields in **users_bonitet** table are: **user_id** ( referencing **user.id**), **bonitet** ( represents the strength of user, it can have 3 values, 1 - 2 - 3, where 3 is the best ), and tstamp ( stores the time of bonitet insert. Every time when bonitet value changes for some user, new row is inserted with tstamp of that insert and of course new bonitet value.). So basically some user can have bonitet of 1 indicating that he is in bad situation, but after some time it can change to 3 indicating that he is doing great, and time of that change is stored in **tstamp**.

Now, I will just list other tables that we need to use in query, and then I will explain why. Tables are: **user**, **club**, **club_offer** and **club_territories**.

Some users ( companies ) are members of a club. Member of the club can have some club offers ( he is representing his products to the people and other club members ) and he is operating on some territory.

What I need to do is to get bonitet value for every club offer ( made by some user who is member of a club ) but only for specific territory with id of 1100000; Since bonitet values are changing over time for each user, that means that I need to get the latest one only. So if some user have bonitet of 1 at 21.01.2012, but later at 26.05.2012 it has changed to 2, I need to get only 2, since that is the current value.

I made an SQL Fiddle with example db schema and query that I am using right now. On this small database, query is working what I want and it is fast, but on real database it is very slow, and sometimes do not execute at all.

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0d98/2

My question is: am I using wrong query to get all this data ? I am getting right result but maybe my query is bad and that is why it executes so slow ? How can I speed it up ? I have tried by putting indexes using phpmyadmin, but it didn't help very much.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT users_bonitet.user_id, users_bonitet.bonitet, users_bonitet.tstamp,
       club_offer.id AS offerId, club_offer.rank

FROM users_bonitet

INNER JOIN (
     SELECT max( tstamp ) AS lastDate, user_id
     FROM users_bonitet
     GROUP BY user_id
)lastDate ON users_bonitet.tstamp = lastDate.lastDate

AND users_bonitet.user_id = lastDate.user_id

JOIN users ON users_bonitet.user_id = users.id
JOIN club ON users.id = club.user_id
JOIN club_offer ON club.id = club_offer.club_id
JOIN club_territories ON club.id = club_territories.club_id

WHERE club_territories.territory_id = 1100000
```

So I am selecting bonitet values for all club offers made by users that are members of a club and operate on territory with an id of 1100000. Important thing is that I am selecting club_offer.id AS offerId, because I need to use that offerId in my application code so I can do some calculations based on bonitet values returned for each offer, and insert data that was calculated to the field "club_offer.rank" for each row with the id of offerId.

Comment: Can you make an sql fiddle with sample data?

Comment: Read my post please, link is there. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0d98/2

Comment: What's happens if you instead of users_bonitet.tstamp use lastDate.lastDate in SELECT statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query looks fine. I suspect your query performance may be improved if you add a compound index to help the subquery that finds the latest entry from `users_botinet` for each user.

The subquery is:

```
   SELECT max( tstamp ) AS lastDate, user_id
     FROM users_bonitet
    GROUP BY user_id
```

If you add `(user_id, tstamp)` as an index to this table, that subquery can be satisfied with a very efficient [*loose index scan*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-optimization.html).

```
ALTER TABLE users_bonitet ADD KEY maxfinder (user_id, tstamp);
```

Notice that if this `users_botinet` table had an autoincrementing id number in it, your subquery could be refactored to use that instead of `tstamp`. That would eliminate the possibility of duplicates and be even more efficient, because there's a unique id for joining.  Like so.

```
  FROM users_botinet
  INNER JOIN (
         SELECT MAX(id) AS id
           FROM users_botinet
          GROUP BY user_id
       ) ubmax ON users_botinet.id = ubmax.id
```

In this case your compound index would be `(user_id, id`.

Pro tip:  Don't add lots of indexes unless you know you need them. It's a good idea to read up on how indexes can help you. For example. http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using id in subquery. But using maxfinder index slows down the query by 3 times.

Comment: Strange; `maxfinder` looks good.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` with and without `maxfinder`.  (You can leave the index in place, but use `IGNORE INDEX(maxfinder)` in two places.)  Also use SQL_NO_CACHE to make sure the Query cache is throwing off timings.